# Change value attribute names in dropdown and make it function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code of mine is working as I want it to work but now i face a issue is how do i store the option values in db as inside the values there are numbering value="1" or value="2". can i not make it to work by putting value="1000" and when i select it the value on the other select changes to value="250"?

here is my code

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
    
     $("#mpyment").change(function(){
      var mpyment = $(this).val();
      $('#emi option').eq(mpyment).prop('selected', true);
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="mpyment" class="float-right ralign" id="mpyment">
            <option value="" disabled selected>--select payment--</option>
            <option value="1">1000</option>
            <option value="2">1500</option>
          </select>

             <select name="emi" class="float-right ralign" id="emi">
            <option value="" disabled selected>--select emi--</option>
            <option value="1">250</option>
            <option value="2">450</option>
          </select>
```

Really appreciate your kind help and input here.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you means you want to select option by the `1000, 1500, 250, 450` not by `1,2` right?

Comment: Nirav yes exactly

Comment: as i ran your code it is working properly.

Comment: i even want to change the <option value="1000">1000</option> and <option value="250">250</option> like this

Comment: than you can use custom attribute. let me make example for you

Comment: would appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can use like this.

Hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mpyment").change(function() {
    var mpyment = $('option:selected',this).data("value");
    $('#emi option[data-value="'+mpyment+'"]').prop('selected', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="mpyment" class="float-right ralign" id="mpyment">
  <option value="" disabled selected>--select payment--</option>
  <option value="1000" data-value="1">1000</option>
  <option value="1500" data-value="2">1500</option>
</select>

<select name="emi" class="float-right ralign" id="emi">
  <option value="" disabled selected>--select emi--</option>
  <option value="250" data-value="1">250</option>
  <option value="450" data-value="2">450</option>
</select>
```